# Errors in eclipse for maven and alfresco sdk

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, alfresco

I am working on a java maven project in eclipse using the m2e plugin. I configured maven plugin with eclipse but some problems occurred.

1.[image]

2. Alfesco maven sdk link is not working in eclipse its not downloading the required Archetype which is alfresco- amp archtype.  [image]

I searched them alot bu I am new to maven and eclipse and, after a day of googling, I still haven't managed to find a solution for this.

**Update**

Maven Settings are given as follows is there any problem in maven settings. Is there any problem with local repository/catalog then how to change it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Setttings.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

```
 <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>172.16.0.9</host>
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy ? As far as I see, the alfresco archetypes are in the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: yes i am working behind proxy and i am using external maven plugin .. i am adding maven plugin and settings.xml file in my question.

Comment: Since you are working behind a proxy, could you please show your eclipse "network connections" configuration ?